# How can I deal with foreign key constraints in MySql + Laravel on delete?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a **slots** table that looks something like this. Overly simplified, but it helps for demonstration:

| Date | Service_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-11-03 | 1 |
| 2021-11-04 | 2 |

Basically, a user picks a date and the service he wants. This is a booking system. There is also a foreign key relationship from service_id above to the id of the **services** table.

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Haircut |
| 2 | Manicure |
| 3 | Massage |

My migration for the slots table contains the following:

```
Schema::table('slots', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->foreignId('service_id')->nullable()->constrained();
});
```

What I want to do now is to be able to delete a service without having any errors being thrown from existing records in the slots table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can [$table->nullOnDelete();](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)  but this way the column Service_id in slots table should be nullable:

```
Schema::table('slots', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->foreignId('service_id')->nullable()->constrained()->nullOnDelete();
});
```

this way, the corresponding row in slots will have null in `Service_id` column.

the other way is to use `->cascadeOnDelete()`, this way, when you delete a service, all related slots will be deleted:

```
 Schema::table('slots', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->foreignId('service_id')->nullable()->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
});
```